# How to use Windows Terminal as debug console in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-terminal

I want to use Windows Terminal as my debug console in Visual Studio Code. I don't like VS Code's integrated terminal. How do I do It?

Here is my launch.json file in my python project:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File External Terminal",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Looking at the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes), set the `console` field in launch.json to `externalTerminal`.

Then, to choose the specific external terminal program to use on windows, use the `terminal.external.windowsExec` setting. Ex.

```json
"terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"
```

Just replace the cmd.exe path with whatever path your Windows Terminal is installed at. Try `"C:\\Users\\{user-name}\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\wt.exe"` or `"%LocalAppData%\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\wt.exe"`.

---

If neither of those work, you could try set Windows Terminal to be the default terminal used on your system, which according to [this Microsoft devblog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-as-your-default-command-line-experience/), you can do in three ways:

- In Windows Settings > Privacy and Security > For developers > Terminal > Choose the default terminal app to hose the user interface for command-line applications > Windows Terminal
- In Windows Terminal > Settings > Default Terminal Application > Windows Terminal
- In Powershell Properties > Terminal > Default Terminal Application > Windows Terminal

That devblog is for Windows 11.[This page on tenforums.com](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/180053-how-change-default-terminal-application-windows-10-a.html) suggests that the properties page and Windows Terminal settings approach should work starting at Windows 10 build 21390 with Windows Terminal Preview v1.9.1445.0 or higher.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 and It doesn't have Privacy and Security option In settings. In my Windows Terminal I can't see Default Terminal Application option. Does what you said only apply to Windows 11?

Comment: @AlperAkca I've updated my answer after I learned something new.

Comment: I did the first things you said. But now the **command prompt** for debugging opens.

Comment: @AlperAkca Did you replace the cmd path in the code block with the path to your windows terminal installation?

Comment: Yeah, I did. I changed cmd path with `"%LocalAppData%\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\wt.exe"`.

Comment: Try it with the version where you don't use `%`: `"C:\\Users\\AlperAkca\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\wt.exe"` or whatever it is for you with your username on your computer.

Comment: Same thing happend. @user